# car and cdr in Scheme won't give expected output

Tags: scheme

I'm learning scheme and when trying to use car and cdr in a very simply function I don't get the expected results:

```
(define test
  (lambda (lst)
    '((car lst).cdr (lst))))
```

And when running

```
(test '(a.b.c))
```

I get output:

```
'((car lst) .cdr (lst))
```

How do I make it use the car and cdr functions and not treat them like strings?

Comment: you commented the car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `'` or `quote` is a procedure that creates constant.
That's why you got `'((car lst) .cdr (lst))` as output, You basically calculated the string expression of `((car lst) .cdr (lst))`. Read [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/quote.html) about it.
The correct form of what you wanted to do should be written like this:

```
(define test
    (lambda (lst)
        (list (car lst) (cdr lst))))

(test '(a b c))
```

The output will be a list in which the first item will be the `car` of `'(a b c)` which is `a` and the second item will be the `cdr` of `'(a b c)` which is the list `(b c)`.
The output will be: `(a (b c))`

Answer (score 3):

When you quote something, like `'(1 2 3 4)` the result will be the data structure created at read time without any evaluation.

```
'((car lst) .cdr (lst))))
; ==> ((car lst) .cdr (lst)))
```

It does exactly what you tell it to. It's like complaining that evaluating the string `"5 + 5"` doesn't give you `10`.

If you actually want the car of something you do this:

```
(define (test lst)
  (car lst))

(test '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 1
```

You can make a shallow copy of a pair like this:

```
(define (shallow-copy pair)
  (cons (car pair) (cdr pair)))

(define test-value (list 1 2 3))
(define shallow-value (shallow-copy test-value)))

(eq? test-value shallow-value)            ; ==> #f
(eq? (cdr test-value) (cdr shallow-value)); ==> #t
```

I have no idea what your procedure supposed to do so cannot help you further.